# Octave 4.2 Command Window is Adding Blank Lines

Tags: matlab, windows-10, octave

First, I am new to Octave, but fairly familiar with Matlab. After using Octave for a short time I've noticed that the cursor in the command window will regularly add a new, empty line. Sometime this can be in the middle of typing a command. If I let the window sit with no input, the cursor will eventually advance all the way down the page and keep going.

I have never seen anything like this, and I do not know where to even begin to fix it.

Thanks!

[Command Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTdB7.png)

Comment: that's ... odd. you should probably report that as a bug instead.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I can't see how a bugreport would help here as long it can't be reproduced. Connor: what is "regularly add a new line"? Every nth typed character? Does this only happen in the GUI or also in the CLI?

Comment: @Andy well yes, but a bug report doesn't play the role of a support ticket anyway; my thinking was more along the lines of adding the issue to the bug tracker so that it's searchable (if not already present), such that if more people encounter this issue, the sum of all circumstances surrounding it might eventually help crack it.

Comment: @Andy The cursor would advance to the next line, but would not start the line with '>>>', it would simply be a continuation of the previous line but farther down the page... I managed to clear it up by reinstalling Octave...

Comment: There is a deleted answer below pointing out this bug has been reported as https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50692 . No idea why the admins deleted it, but reproducing here as a comment in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

My alternative answer is that that a bug report should be filed so that this issue gets fixed.  I have the exact same problem.  Every 30 seconds, when system time hits an even minute and 30 seconds past the minute, the command window cursor skips to the next line.  One can still type to the command line and hit enter in the end. The command line now split at random points to several lines will be successfully computed.  The problem is that you can not edit the line back past the inserted line break and the whole thing looks really messy.  I tried to un-install and re-install but that did not help in my case.  I use octave-4.2.1-w64-installer.exe

Comment: I installed Octave 5.1.0 and this bug is still present making Octave GUI Command Window pretty much unusable.

Comment: I got a brand new laptop.  This time Windows 10 (previous was Win7).  The bug is still present in a brand new installation of Octave.  I also noticed the bug in the command line interface!  Not every time though, only rarely.  Also, the bug was present before I installed matlab on the new laptop.  I was kind of suspecting my matlab installation would interfere with octave but now that is ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Boring solution (and hopefully permanent): I uninstalled and reinstalled the same version of Octave and this bug seems to have gone away. Not very convenient, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem caused by a 3rd party application. I've seen this issue on a computer with Druva inSync. Disabling the Druva inSync service (not the client) stops this. inSync injects itself in applications using the Windows file dialog. Apparently this code contains a bug and accidentally writes a line feed (LF) to a file handle belonging to the application. The problem might also go away with a different Octave version. In particular the 4.2.x and 4.4.x seem to behave differently.